# Read SQL Server 2005 ldf file

Tags: c#, sql-server

i will try to explain my question in details. In a program that i am writitng i need to read the content of log file for a certain database. I google a little bit and found that ldf is binary file. But i was no able to find the format of the file or any tutorial showing how to read this file. I am writing the program on C# but any examples on any programing languages will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't mind, why do you need do that? This seems a wrong way to anywhere...

Comment: You don't find any examples because this isn't something you should be doing.

Comment: I know at first look it seems wrong to read this file but i am trying to do something like the SQL Log Rescue but i need to implement it as part of bigger program so i need to know how htey read the file i cant just use the progrma

Comment: maybe if you can to add more context...

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the log file is not documented and not public, even the commercial log readers will not pick up everything from the log - they most likely will of reverse engineered it or hired ex-SQL developers who know about it.

Before you concern yourself with decoding the physical file start by trying to decode the output from:

```
select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
```

That will get you a formatted output of the log and the log binary data in a field - even that is not trivial to decode. As well as the log file format, you will have to have a very indepth knowledge of SQL itself to understand the entries properly.

Overall - I think you are better off buying one of the existing commercial packages, because if you need to ask about the format - your internal knowledge of SQL is unlikely to be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Late one but hopefully useful…

There is a log reading API you might want to try [ApexSQL Log API](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_logapi.aspx). This is a commercial tool but it has a free trial.

Other options are using undocumented functions such as DBCC LOG and fn_dblog.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why do you need to implement this, but seems wrong, at least.

Every [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system) are implemented to keep you away from filesystem, as it's supposed to deal with operational system details and to provide concurrency, for instance. If you try to read that LDB from a running database you'll add weight in somewhere not designed to support it.

*Maybe* you just want to check who made some database update; in this case, you can to use triggers to log (into a regular *database* table), a timestamp and current user.

This option is far more simple than what you proposed and can be achieved in a documented way.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command as @Andrew Said:

```
Select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
```

And for more information see this link : [How Do You Decode A Simple Entry in the Transaction Log](http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/)

Comment: thats my blog entry btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sql Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm) from RedGate. If you do find how the file is formatted let the rest of us know.